# Create EFS accesspoints for an existing EFS using CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-efs

Is it possible to create accesspoints for an existing EFS through CloudFormation?

For example, in the CloudFormation template:

First reference the EFS by a parameter

```
FileSystemResource:
Type: 'AWS::EFS::FileSystem'
Properties:
  FileSystemId: !Ref some_param
  BackupPolicy:
    Status: ENABLED
  PerformanceMode: generalPurpose
  Encrypted: true
  ThroughputMode: bursting
```

Then reference the EFS to create the access point?

```
SomeAccessPoint:
Type: 'AWS::EFS::AccessPoint'
Properties:
  FileSystemId: !Ref FileSystemResource
```

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why you can do?

Answer (score 0):

You have to [import](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-existing-stack.html) your existing filesystem into CloudFormation first, before you can do this.

Comment: How do I reference the EFS that has been imported into a CloudFormation stack? The goal is to have the accesspoints and EFS sitting in one stack so that their lifecycles are tied together.

Comment: @KeyserSoze Just like you have now in `SomeAccessPoint`. `FileSystemId` is wrong in `FileSystemResource`.